# Stacked Chart from Prometheus data in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I've been trying to create a stacked bar chart in Grafana from Prometheus data but struggling and to be honest, I'm not even entirely sure that what I'm trying to do is possible. I've had a go using the old graph panel and the new bar chart panel - but to be honest I'm finding the new bar chart panel fairly unintuitive and documentation is vague. I'm working with a time-series counter for nginx requests split by response code. A sample of the data in Prometheus is:

`nginx_vts_server_requests_total{code="2xx", host="example.com", instance="localhost:443", job="nginx_vts"}`

I was hoping to create a stacked chart based on the number of requests from the last 12 hours, taking the last value of:

`increase(nginx_vts_server_requests_total[12h])`

I haven't included an aggregate as I'm only working with a single instance.

I am hoping to create something similar to the this image (mocked up in excel):

[image]

If anyone has created such a chart before in Grafana based on Prometheus data, I'd be very grateful if you could show me how it's done (if it is in fact possible at all). The screenshot at the top of the page at https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/visualizations/bar-chart/ suggests that it is possible to do such groupings although this example is not stacked.

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with a similar problem. This is the query I used; which is quite similar:

```
sum(rate(http_requests_received_total[1h])) by (code,instance)
```

- First make sure the *Bar Chart* option *Stacking* is set to *Normal*.
- Set the query *Type* to be *Instant* since we'll only use the last value.
- Go on to *Transform* the query. Remember the *Table view* option is your friend in grasphing what is going on. Add in this order:

  - Add *Reduce* transform to reduce *Series to rows*. I use *Max*-calculations, but remember we really have just one.
  - Add *Extract fields* transform to split *Field* into separate fields.
  - If you want to do anything with the ordering this is the place to add a *Sort by* transform.
  - Add *Grouping to matrix* transform to create new columns from the new `code` field. Use `code` as *Column*, `instance` as *Row* and *Max* as *Cell Value*.

PS: If you get errors use *Grafana Explore* to check that the values look the way you imagine them. Be especially on the lookout for empty values on `code`and `instance`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is for future reference purposes, the key part from @thoredge response that worked for my case is the `Grouping to matrix` transform.

The query I had in prometheus was:

```
sum (gitlab_ci_pipeline_job_duration_seconds{job_name=~"Random job matching.*"}) by (ref,job_name)
```

The data transformation I configured was:

[image]

The results look like:

[image]